# How do I get my floating div that contains a vertical carousel to not overflow the slider div underneath it?

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I have a vertical carousel that is in a floating div that is on top of a div that contains a horizontal slider. The floating div carousel contains scrolling logos that extend past the slider and pushes down the next div. How can I contain the floating div inside the bottom slider div?

This is the html code.

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-1">
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider-1">
            <li>
                <img src="images/slide-1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="home">Welcome To Company</h3>
                </div>
           </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/slide-2.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="home">Welcome To Company</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/slide-3.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="home">Welcome To Company</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/slide-4.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="home">Welcome To Company</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/slide-5.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="home">Welcome To Company</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        </div>
                <div id="scrollbox">
            <ul class="scroll-img">
            <li><img class="hotel-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></li>
            <li><img class="hotel-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></li>
            <li><img class="hotel-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></li>
            <li><img class="hotel-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></li>
            <li><img class="hotel-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></li>
            <li><img class="hotel-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code.

```
.slider {
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

.rslides {
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.rslides img {
display: block;
height: auto;
float: left;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
}

.layer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
text-align: center;
}

.caption {
position: absolute;
top: 38%;
left: 14%;
}

.caption h3 {
text-align: left;
font-size: 38px;
font-weight: 800;
line-height: 40px;
color: #FFF;
width: 80%;
}

.caption h3.home {
text-align: left;
font-size: 52px;
font-weight: 800;
line-height: 50px;
color: #FFF;
width: 100%;
}

.slider #scrollbox {
background-color: rgba(2,56,122,0.6);
position: relative;
z-index: 75;
right: 75px;
top: 87px;
width: 185px;
float: right;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
}
.slider #scrollbox .scroll-img {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Look into `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have all of the relevant code and can see what is happening.